# xsd.exe replaces my custom type with string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I'm using xsd.exe to generate a C# class from an XSD schema. Here is what I have in the schema:

```
<xs:element name="SyslogServerSettings" type="SyslogServerType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="SyslogServerType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <meta:version added-in="5.11" />
                <meta:content-type>application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.SyslogSettings</meta:content-type>
            </xs:appinfo>
            <xs:documentation source="since">5.11</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Allows a user to configure syslog server settings for the gateway
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>

        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VCloudExtensibleType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TenantSyslogServerSettings"
                        type="TenantSyslogServerSettingsType" minOccurs="0"
                        maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:appinfo>
                                <meta:version added-in="5.11" />
                            </xs:appinfo>
                            <xs:documentation source="modifiable">always
                            </xs:documentation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                                Tenant syslog server settings
                            </xs:documentation>
                            <xs:documentation source="required">false
                            </xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

And also the definition of TenantSyslogServerSettings:

```
<xs:complexType name="TenantSyslogServerSettingsType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation source="since">5.11</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Tenant syslog server settings.
                If logging is configured for firewall rules, the logs will be directed to these syslog servers
                along with the provider syslog servers.
                Only one tenant syslog server ip can be configured.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SyslogServerIp" type="IpAddressType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation source="modifiable">always</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        syslog server ip address.
                    </xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation source="required">false</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

The IpAddressType on the other hand is defined as:

```
<xs:simpleType name="IpAddressType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation source="since">0.9</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                A valid IPv4 address or "Any".
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

And in the final generated C# class I get:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("SyslogServerSettings", Namespace="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class SyslogServerType : VCloudExtensibleType {

        private string[] tenantSyslogServerSettingsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("SyslogServerIp", IsNullable=false)]
        public string[] TenantSyslogServerSettings {
            get {
                return this.tenantSyslogServerSettingsField;
            }
            set {
                this.tenantSyslogServerSettingsField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get the logic behind replacing the custom type with string[], but this is not what I want. I want the custom type TenantSyslogServerSettings generated as well, even if it's just a class containing one string property. How can I make xsd.exe generate it?

Comment: Your definition is not about class with string property. It is about type inherited from string. This is your problem (cause string is sealed class).

Comment: Do you mean the IpAddressType? It really is a type inherited from string. But TenantSyslogServerSettingsType should be a custom type, containing string property (it's a ComplexType containing one property of IpAddressType(string).